# C# Generics with IronPython Type Parameters

Tags: c#, .net, clr, ironpython, dynamic-language-runtime

So, the situation is I have a C# generic class named `Foo` with a template parameter `T` which has the `new()` constraint. I've declared my classes something like this:

```
class Baz
{
    public Baz() { }
}

class Foo<T>
    where T : Baz, new()
{
    // blah blah
}
```

And in Python:

```
class Bar(Baz):
    def __init__(self):
        """ do various things here """
```

However, if, in Python, I try to do `Foo[Bar]`, I get an error telling me that my `Bar` class violates the constraints (namely the `new()` constraint) on `Foo<T>`.

What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no default constructor for IronPython objects.  They need to carry some additional mutable state with them, the Python type, which must be provided when the class is instantiated.  That type is used to resolve any virtual overloads and other methods when called dynamically.

Comment: Ah yes, I figured as such when my I realized that templates were actually discarding all my Python type information. Thanks for confirming this.

Comment: Can someone elaborate or put up and example on this? My knowledge of the inner workings of python just aren't helping me leap to what this should look in code.

Comment: I just tried a few things and found C# function

    somefunc<sometype>(string x) { dostuff(); }

must be called as 

    somefunc[sometype]("some string")